# Invalid command 'PHPIniDir', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration в apache

Tags: php, apache, apache2

Я хочу поставить PHP на Apache 2.4 все делаю правильно но apache говорит что нету такой команды (PHPIniDir)

Вот строчки конфига связаные с PHP:

```
LoadModule php_module "C:/php-8.1.10/php8apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php-8.1.10"
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: А в доках по врачу есть такая функция "PHPIniDir"?

Comment: Не знаю, вроде как есть

Comment: Ну а если посмотреть?

Comment: Ну если яудалю эту строчку то никакой пхп работать не будет